# Is Quarto able to render documents with ipython magic?

Tags: python, quarto

Consider the following document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
jupyter: r-reticulate
---

```{python}
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```
````

when rendered, it produces the following error:

```
An error occurred while executing the following cell:
------------------
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
------------------
```

So my question is: Is Quarto able to render documents with `ipython` magic?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out that it works if I use `{ipython}` instead of `{python}`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
jupyter: r-reticulate
---

```{ipython}
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```
````

**EDIT**

With the help of @shafee, to whom I very much thank, it was found out that `quarto` can render `ipython` magic. Although `rpy2` was installed in `r-reticulate` environment, the problem occurred. However, after having installed `rpy2` in the default `python` environment, the issue vanished, even when using `r-reticulate` environment.

That is weird, and an issue has been filed:

https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto/issues/53

Comment: Does this work? As per my understanding `quarto` ignores the code chunk of `ipython`!

Comment: It works in the sense that it silents the error, but the truth is that I have not been able to use `ipython` magic at all inside a `quarto` document, @shafee. I do not know it is a bug or something not implemented in purpose.

Comment: I think, *it silents the error* because that it does not even execute this chunk.

Comment: Maybe, @shafee, you are right! I think I am going to open an issue on GitHub to report this.

Comment: Done so, @shafee: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto/issues/53

Comment: Hey I am actually able to use that magic from quarto now.

Comment: Could you please post here your approach, @shafee?

Comment: All i did just installing `rpy2` in the python environment and then call `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` from a `python` chunk, not `ipython` and also with `jupyter: pythoh3`. So do you have `rpy2` installed in that `r-reticulate` environment? and some version info about quarto would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I do have `rpy2` installed in the environment `r-reticulate`, @shafee.

Comment: My `quarto`version is: 1.2.280.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250893/discussion-between-shafee-and-pauls).

Comment: I have just found out that, if I do not use `r-reticulate`, but use default `python` environment, `ipython` magic works fine.