# Quarto ignores ipython output

Tags: python, quarto

Consider the following `quarto` document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
jupyter: r-reticulate
---

```{ipython}
print('hello1')
```

```{python}
print('hello2')
```
````

The `pdf` document does not print `hello1`, but prints `hello2`. It seems that `quarto` ignores `ipython` output. Is that expected?

Comment: I think `quarto` is not ignoring `ipython`, but it ignores the chunk itself (i.e. doesn't execute the chunk and keep it as is)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @shafee. What you argue is also a possibility.

Comment: Are you sure that [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75025012/10858321) to your previous question works?

Comment: I have just replied to your comment in my previous question, @shafee.